# Laravel project creation issue

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

When I create a laravel project everything goes smoothly with composer. However when I try to access the default index.php page i get a 500 error. After checking the logs I found it was a syntax error in Laravels source code. I found that it was '...' infront of the variable.

> [Wed Nov 02 01:47:45.658110 2016] [:error] [pid 4561] [client
>   70.66.236.55:55751] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /var/www/html/proj-dir/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 475

After fixing that a new one would pop up. And this repeated several more times. Not sure if they are supposed to be there or not, but I assumed that '...$args' was not a valid syntax (even for laravel)

After "fixing" all the errors I get taken to an actual error message in the browser!

`

```
>     ErrorException in Gate.php line 132:
>     Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::policy(), called in
> /var/www/html/proj-dir/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
> on line 237 and defined
>     1. in Gate.php line 132
>     2. at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::policy(), called in
> /var/www/html/proj-dir/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
> on line 237 and defined',
> '/var/www/html/proj-dir/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php',
> '132', array('class' => array('App\Model',
> 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy'), 'this' => object(Gate))) in Gate.php line
> 132
>     3. at Gate->policy(array('App\Model', 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy')) in Facade.php line 237
>     4. at Facade::__callStatic('policy', array('App\Model', 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy')) in AuthServiceProvider.php line 25
>     5. at Gate::policy('App\Model', 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy') in AuthServiceProvider.php line 25
>     6. at AuthServiceProvider->registerPolicies() in AuthServiceProvider.php line 26
>     7. at AuthServiceProvider->boot()
>     8. at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthServiceProvider), 'boot'), array()) in Container.php line 508
>     9. at Container->call(array(object(AuthServiceProvider), 'boot')) in Application.php line 769
>     10. at Application->bootProvider(object(AuthServiceProvider)) in Application.php line 752
>     11. at Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(object(AuthServiceProvider),
> '13')
>     12. at array_walk(array(object(EventServiceProvider), object(RoutingServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider),
> object(CookieServiceProvider), object(DatabaseServiceProvider),
> object(EncryptionServiceProvider), object(FilesystemServiceProvider),
> object(FoundationServiceProvider),
> object(NotificationServiceProvider),
> object(PaginationServiceProvider), object(SessionServiceProvider),
> object(ViewServiceProvider), object(AppServiceProvider),
> object(AuthServiceProvider), object(EventServiceProvider),
> object(RouteServiceProvider)), object(Closure)) in Application.php
> line 753
>     13. at Application->boot() in BootProviders.php line 17
>     14. at BootProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
>     15. at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment',
> 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration',
> 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging',
> 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions',
> 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades',
> 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders',
> 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line
> 253
>     16. at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 144
>     17. at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
>     18. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

`

I have tried recreating the project multiple times, but always end up at the same place. Not really sure how to proceed.

Comment: Please insert your code here where you found the error.

Comment: You need PHP 5.6.x to support that feature.

Comment: Download latest xampp, and than try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI these aren't syntax errors. Most probably you're using an old version of PHP. Make sure your server meets following requirements:

> PHP >= 5.6.4
>
> OpenSSL PHP Extension
>
> PDO PHP Extension
>
> Mbstring PHP Extension
>
> Tokenizer PHP Extension
>
> XML PHP Extension

Also don't forget to give required permissions to directories like storage, bootstraps.

> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions.
>   Directories within the  **storage** and the **bootstrap/cache** directories
>   should be **writable** by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you
>   are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should
>   already be set.

Here you'll find everything at a glance that are needed to up and running a laravel project.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3

Comment: I had multiple versions of php installed. Un-installed all of them and then re-installed 5.6 and it worked